# Rundeck - Unsupported major.minor version

Tags: java, version, mismatch, rundeck

I'm getting this error when launching the install launcher.
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -jar rundeck-launcher-2.8.2.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/dtolabs/rundeck/ExpandRunServer : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_131-b31)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b31, mixed mode)

The requirements for rundeck say that this should be a supported version.

from the manual

" $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_131-b31)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.131-b31, mixed mode)"

What did I do wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Rundeck 2.8.0+ requires Java 8 to run:

> ### Upgrading to Rundeck 2.8 from earlier versions
>
> ## Java 8 is required
>
> Rundeck server now requires Java 8.

http://rundeck.org/docs/upgrading/index.html#java-8-is-required

I'm assuming the manual is outdated.

Comment: Thanks - I was afraid of that.